# How to communicate via PKCS#11 with a HSM

Tags: python, encryption, pkcs#11, hsm

I have a Python application which needs to encrypt data. The symmetric keys lying in a separate hardware called HSM.

I have implemented a wrapper in python

```
pip install python-pkcs11
```

and set the path to the c-pkcs11-library for initialization.

```
lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PATH_TO_C-PKCS11_LIB'])
```

But what next? How can I configure the whole wrapper or the C-library to watch in the HSM for the key?

And how does the app and the HSM communicate? Is it via HTTP?

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad. Have a look at [examples](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#getting-started) in the documentation. Use [`get_key`](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pkcs11.Session.get_key) to lookup key in HSM and [`encrypt`](https://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pkcs11.EncryptMixin.encrypt) to encrypt.

Example code encrypting a block of zeroes in CBC mode with zero IV using AES key `TEST` stored in HSM token `DEMO`:

```
import os
import pkcs11

lib = pkcs11.lib(os.environ['PKCS11_MODULE'])
token = lib.get_token(token_label='DEMO')
with token.open(user_pin='1234') as session:
    key = session.get_key(key_type=pkcs11.mechanisms.KeyType.AES, label='TEST')
    iv = bytes.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000')
    data = bytes.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000')
    ciphertext = key.encrypt(data=data, mechanism=pkcs11.mechanisms.Mechanism.AES_CBC, mechanism_param=iv)
    print(ciphertext.hex())
```

You definitely should read the [PKCS#11 specification](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/os/pkcs11-base-v2.40-os.html) and SDK documentation for your HSM.

Good luck with your project!